# How do I access the File System API of emscripten when compiled with MODULARIZE option?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

If I compile my C++ code with `emcc` without `-s MODULARIZE=1 -s 'EXPORT_NAME="createMyModule"'`, I can load my WebAssembly and access the [File System API](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html) like this:

HTML:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Module = {
    onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
      console.log('Module loaded!');
      if (FS.mkdir) {
        console.log('File System API available!');
      }
    }
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myWebAssemblyModule.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="my.js"></script>
```

Log:

```
Module loaded!
File System API available!
```

But if I add `-s MODULARIZE=1 -s 'EXPORT_NAME="createMyModule"'` as compiler options, and try to access the File System API based on a Promise, it doesn't work:

HTML:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="myWebAssemblyModule.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="my.js"></script>
```

my.js:

```js
createMyModule().then(MyModule => {
  console.log('Module loaded!');
  if (MyModule.FS.mkdir) {
    console.log('File System API available!');
  }
});
```

Log:

```
Module loaded!
```

So how can I access the File System API with the "MODULARIZED/Promise based" approach?

`MyModule.FS` is accessible btw., but not `MyModule.FS.mkdir`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `FS` available in a modularized build, you have to export it explicitly:

```
emcc ... -s 'EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=["FS"]'
```